# jQuery: change a css value if a option is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I'm trying to make an option dropdown menu and I got stuck when I try to show a textbox if the option 'other' is selected.

there's what I have:

```
<span id="con-country"><label for="country">Country: </label>
<select name="country" required="required">
<option value="usa">United States</option>
<option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
<option id="other" value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</span>

<span id="con-specify">
<label for="specify">Specify: </label>
<input type="text" name="specify" id="c-specify" required="required"></input>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#con-specify{
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: none;
}
```

Simple huh?, the problem is that I don't know how to do the code in jQuery

So, if the user select other in the menu, then the textbox should appear, how can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, it may help to think of this as multiple problems: "How do I do something when the user selects an option?", "How do I check which option was selected?", "How do I get an HTML element?", "How do I change the CSS of an element?"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($){
    //change event handler for the select
    $('select[name="country"]').change(function(){
        //set the visibility of the specify element based on the value of select
        $('#con-specify').toggle(this.value == 'other')
    }).change();//fire the change event so that the initial visibility is set
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MMvbA/)

Read more about each of the methods in http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jQuery, simply use `$('#con-specify').show()` and  `$('#con-specify').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a jQuery link in the head of the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
```

The dropdown menu should have an id (ie: country).

Then your javascript would look something like this:

```
    window.onload = function() {
      $('#con-specify').hide();

      $('#country').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'other') {
            $('#con-specify').show();
        } else {
            $('#con-specify').hide();
        }
      });
    };
```